# How to set VLC for NTSC

Tags: vlc, video-player

I'm viewing a DVD in NTSC format. I see horizontal lines across the picture.

I live in Europe and the videos here run under PAL. Hope to see a good info to set VLC.

Answer (score 2):

In the **Video Settings** (Menu Bar or Rightclick on playing Video) you will find **Deinterlace** and **Deinterlace-Modus**.

Under **Deinterlace** you should choose **on**.

For the **Deinterlace-Modus**, you should go with **Movie NTSC**...

If that does not help instantly, try to play around with the deinterlace settings, until you find the right one.

Have fun watching your movies!

Answer (score 1):

The latest 2016 version of VLC plays PAL and NTSC without having to change any settings. I have a PAL dvd from Australia that plays here in the United States on my VLC on my laptop but my dvd player attached to my tv will not play the PAL because it is not a region free player. Region free dvd players are guaranteed to play any region. They do not cost much.